# Patching kernel for graphics tablet, not sure if it'll work

Tags: drivers, kernel, patch, graphics-tablet

I just got a new graphics tablet that seems to be supported in kernel 3.11, found this: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2624521/

I downloaded the new kernel deb packages from here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-rc1-saucy/ and installed them but apparently nVidia doesn't have drivers for 3.11 yet (nor 3.10) so I had to revert back to 3.8.

Now my question is, can I just follow instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile, and apply that patch to my current kernel in Ubuntu 13.04 or is there any other way I can get this working with no headaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

> The mainline kernels builds are produced for debugging purposes and therefore come with no support. Use them at your own risk.

The kernels are supplied "as is" with no guarantee that it will work, less so with a patch.

Have you ever compiled a kernel before ?

If not, see: http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/kernel

You can post back if you get errors or problems, but again support may be limited at best.

Comment: I found this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel, I think I'll follow those steps and see if I can figure out how to patch it and create a deb.

Comment: My question is basically about compatibility, not sure the patch would work with 3.8.

Comment: no way to tell without either looking at the source code and the patch or trying to apply and compile.