# Patched kernel, everything works except the device Huion 580 that was supposed to work with the patch

Tags: drivers, kernel, tablet, patch

This is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321331/patching-kernel-for-graphics-tablet-not-sure-if-itll-work).

I downloaded kernel 3.9.10, applied the [patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2624521/) with `patch -p1 < ../huion.patch`, then I followed [this instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel) to compile the kernel, then I installed the deb packages that were generated, rebooted and I'm typing this from the new kernel, `uname -a` reports my custom build. Everything good so far.

Now the problem, I connect the Huion 580 tablet and it doesn't work. My `lsusb` looks like this:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 256c:006e <-- This is the tablet!!!!
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 4168:1011  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04a9:1746 Canon, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:2111 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 03f0:a707 Hewlett-Packard
```

But the tablet is not in `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                           id=2   [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ reserved Targus Wireless Optical Mouse    id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                          id=3   [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam HD-2200                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What could be the problem? I can't use mainline kernel 3.11 (which supposedly includes the patch) because there are no nVidia drivers that work yet.

Before applying the patch I run `make oldconfig` and left everything as default pressing enter a bunch of times. Then I applied the patch and run that command again and it asked about Huion driver with options `[N,m]`, I pressed `N` for `NEW` I think...

Some people [got it working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wizardpen/+bug/994978/comments/7) with this patch, not me. How can I know if the patch was applied and that this device is supposed to get detected? Do I have to load the driver manually somehow?

**Edit:** Compiling kernel again pressing `m` this time, let's see how this goes...

Comment: Did you enable `CONFIG_HID_HUION` in your kernel config?

Comment: I was a bit confused about that bit. Before applying the patch I run `make oldconfig` and left everything as default pressing enter a bunch of times. Then I applied the patch and run that command again and it asked about Huion driver with options `[N,m]`, I pressed `N` for `NEW` I think... Did I do something wrong? Do I have to compile again?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide more details. :) And no, `N` is "don't compile", `y` is "compile in-kernel" (not available for all modules) and `m` is for module build. Can you verify that you have a `hid-huion.o` file in your build tree? If not, then rebuild the kernel with the `m` setting.

Comment: OK, I'm back in 3.8 generic, gonna compile again. Should I patch first and then config or the other way around? I just did it the same way as before and this is the line where I get the choice `Huion tablets (HID_HUION) [N/m/?] (NEW)`

Comment: I see, I pressed `N` so stupid me. I saw `NEW` and assumed wrongly. I'm compiling again, will come back with more details in a couple hours....

Comment: It really should not take hours. GNU Make will skip building all other parts as that's already built! (unless you've ran `make clean`) Essentially it's only compiling the very small patch only now if you reconfigure and recompile. There's no need to compile from scratch. And again please **edit** your question with all this new information. Comments are not fit for that - editing your question is how this site works.

Comment: I'm compiling everything _from scratch_ so it'll take a while...

Comment: I got it working!!!

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working. First download kernel 3.9.10, extract and apply patch:

```
> cd linux-3.9.10
> yes "" | make oldconfig
> patch -p1 < ../path/to/huion.patch
> make oldconfig
  Huion tablets (HID_HUION) [N/m/?] m
> fakeroot make-kpkg -j 4 --initrd --append-to-version=elclanrs kernel-image kernel-headers
  ...
```

After that I installed the packaged debs, rebooted and everything works now, `uname -a` reports custom kernel.

Finally I had to restrict the tablet to only one monitor, the right one in this case. My setup is `(1920+2560)x1440`:

```
xinput set-prop "HUION 580" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.5714 0 0.4285 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Here are the patched kernel debs for Ubuntu 13.04 64bit:

- [linux-headers-3.9.10elclanrs_3.9.10elclanrs-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/otyo4cn4on3ohtl/linux-headers-3.9.10elclanrs_3.9.10elclanrs-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb)
- [linux-image-3.9.10elclanrs_3.9.10elclanrs-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4vrardzpohwg2j/linux-image-3.9.10elclanrs_3.9.10elclanrs-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb)