# Huion 580 graphics tablet not detected after reboot

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

I just bought a Huion 580 graphics tablet. It worked fine out of the box, pressure and all, but when I installed some system updates and rebooted the computer it doesn't work anymore.

In fact, it's not even detected and given a device name or id:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ca:18c4 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:002c Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 256c:006e #My tablet used to be here 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Sony Vaio Jogdial                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M505/B605                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ #My tablet should be here too.
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 Camera                             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I'm pretty sure this is due to the system update [switching my modules to 4.4.0-32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjbHS.png), but I have no idea how to copy the hid_huion (or whatever I need) module/driver over. I've tried installing DIGImend through the .deb file they provide on github but that doesn't change anything.

Any ideas, or results from the terminal I should post?

Edit:
I have read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321802/patched-kernel-everything-works-except-the-device-huion-580-that-was-supposed-t) post, but the person asking the question was using a different kernel version and I have no idea how to patch kernels.

Edit 2:
Another thing that doesn't work:

```
$ modprobe hid_huion
modprobe: FATAL: Module hid_huion not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-32-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it working, according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1575957) launchpad bug.

```
Patola (patola) wrote on 2016-04-28:    #2

I just noticed that although the tablet does not work with the module here:

/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/hid-uclogic.ko

It *DID* work when I manually removed hid_uclogic (rmmod) from memory and insmodded /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-uclogic.ko
```

So the full answer is:

```
sudo rmmod hid_uclogic && sudo insmod /lib/modules/YOUR.KERNEL.VERSION-HERE/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-uclogic.ko
```

Yay!